# Exchanging data in nested Async calls in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, rest, tags, promise

I'm new in the world of AngularJS, and I'm facing with an interesting problem:

I created an Angular factory service that works as a service proxy for the REST service I'm invoking.
My service proxy looks like this:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('myService', ['$http', function($http) {

    var baseAddr = "http://myservice.com";
    var token = "secure_identifier";

    var MyService = {
        doRequest: function(method, path, token, postData) {
            return $http({method: method, url: baseAddr+path, headers: {....}, data:postData });
        }
    }

    return {

        GetGroupUsers: function( id)
        {
            return MyService.doRequest('GET', '/api/groupusers/'+id+'.json', token, null);
        },
        GetUser: function( id)
        {
            return MyService.doRequest('GET', '/api/users/'+id+'.json', token, null);
        }
    }
}]);
```

So GetGroupUsers returns  an array of **userID-s** that are in the given group, and GetUser returns the properties of
a specified member (for example e-mail address, full name, username, birth date).
What I want is query a group, (get the userid-s that are in that group) and attach the name of the users to the array item
with the help of GetUser(userid) method.
I have a controller, in which I query this service via mine proxy service. Here is the relevant part of the controller:

```
//...
MyService.GetGroupUsers(GroupId).then(function(userlist)
{
    //userlist is an array of a complex object that consists of userId-s and groupId-s
    //Suppose that it looks like this:
    // [ {uid: 1, groupId: 1}, {uid: 2, groupId: 1}, {uid: 3, groupId: 1},...,.. ]
    $scope.groups = userlist.data;

    //but i need to attach for every item in the array the name of the selected user
    // [ {uid: 1, groupId: 1,username: 'Alga Rithem'}, {uid: 2, groupId: 1, username:'Anna Nimmity'}, {uid: 3, groupId: 1, username:'Anna Conda'},...,.. ]

    //So I iterate over the userlist
    for (var i = 0; i < userlist.data.length; i++)
    {
        MyService.GetUser(userlist.data[i].uid).
            then(function(user)
            {
                //And here is the problem I'm facing with:
                //The value of variable "i" becomes obsolate, because GetUser call is async to the for-loop
                // when the "then" "callback" executes, the loop may has been finished already!
                //So I dont really know, where to put the value I've just received
                //I need that value of i, what it was when i called the service!               
                $scope.groups[i].name = user.data.name;  //So this is WRONG!
            });
    }
});

//...
```

I solved this problem with a little hack:
I extended the parameterlist of the GetUser(username) with one parameter to GetUser(username,tag). In this tag I can put anything I want to 
retrieve in the callback.

So I modified my code a little bit:

```
//Service proxy

doRequest: function(method, path, token, postData,tag) {
            return $http({method: method, url: baseAddr+path, headers: {....}, data:postData });
        }
//...

GetUser: function( id, tag)
        {
            return MyService.doRequest('GET', '/api/users/'+id+'.json', token, null,tag);
        }
```

Now I can retrieve the valid, past value of I in my controller:

Modified controller code:

```
//...

MyService.GetGroupUsers(GroupId).then(function(userlist)
{    
    $scope.groups = userlist.data;

    for (var i = 0; i < userlist.data.length; i++)
    {
        MyService.GetUser(adat.data[i].uid).
            then(function(user)
            {                
                $scope.groups[parseInt(user.config.tag)].name = user.data.name;  //This Works fine!
            });
    }
});
```

My question is: Is this solution technically correct? What is the best practice for problems like this?
Does AngularJS have a tool for this?

ps: Modifying the REST service API to return the usernames as well is not a solution in this case.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If your API is restful, consider using `$resource` which makes things a lot easier. Also, can you show all information `GetUser` returns exactly?

Comment: Let's assume GetUser returns a JSON object like this:
"{
  "id": 9,
  "email": "myemail@mycompany.com",
  "username": "mynickname"
}"
How would $resource make things easier for me? Somewhere I need to "join" these objects anyway. Isn't that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `.forEach` loop instead of a `for` loop which closes over `i`:

```
 userlist.data.forEach(function(user, i){
        MyService.GetUser(user.uid).
            then(function(user)
            {
                $scope.groups[i].name = user.data.name;  //So this is WRONG!
            });
    }
```

Or you can create a mapping with `.map` and use `$q.all` to make all updates at once:

```
 $q.all(userlist.data.map(function(user){
        return MyService.GetUser(user.uid))
 }).then(function(users){
       // assign to scope, users is an array here and you can use indices
 });
```

Although the real and practical soltution is not making `n` calls for `n` users but creating a method that accepts several UIDs on the server and fetches all the data for them at once as it will load the system less and perform faster since it won't make `n` round trips and http requests.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your first example doesnt slow down the load time of the webpage? I mean forEach makes Service calls sync, so controller will wait till forEach finishes which can be very time consuming. 
In your second solution how can I retrieve the indicies? Can you please link me an article related to this kind of data mapping? I dont really get this thing. Thanks.

Comment: @bkotyik the fact it's doing `.forEach` instead of `for` does not magically make the calls synchronous, it just synchronously makes the calls (note the difference, the calls will still be made asynchronously). In the second example, you can retrieve the indices by matching `users[i] to $scope.groups[i]` you have the whole array.  Your solution is really changing the backend API though.

Comment: +1 question if you dont mind: If any of these Service calls fails in the sequence, how can I realize which one user query failed?

Comment: You can attach `.catch` handlers to promises - see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q